# Pass list of data (object) between activites in Andriod

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable

I have a class `Dice` implementing `Parcelable` like below

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class Dice implements Parcelable {

    int mDiceNumber;
    boolean mDiceClicked = false;


    public Dice(int mDiceNumber, boolean diceClicked) {
        this.mDiceNumber = mDiceNumber;
        mDiceClicked = diceClicked;
    }

    protected Dice(Parcel in) {
        mDiceNumber = in.readInt();
        mDiceClicked = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Dice> CREATOR = new Creator<Dice>() {
        @Override
        public Dice createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Dice(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Dice[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Dice[size];
        }
    };

    public boolean isDiceClicked() {
        return mDiceClicked;
    }

    public void setDiceClicked(boolean diceClicked) {
        mDiceClicked = diceClicked;
    }

    public int getDiceNumber() {
        return mDiceNumber;
    }

    public void setDiceNumber(int diceNumber) {
        mDiceNumber = diceNumber;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mDiceNumber);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (mDiceClicked ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

I have also two activities my *`MainActivity`* and *`SecondActivity`*. In MaiActivity I have an array of my class Dice

```
private Dice[] mDice = new Dice[]{
            new Dice(1, false),
            new Dice(2, false),
            new Dice(3, false),
            new Dice(4, false),
            new Dice(5, false),
            new Dice(6, false)
    };
```

I want to be able to pass my whole array of dice to my *SecondActivity*.

This is what I have done so far:

in *MainActivity*:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Dices", mDice);
 startActivity(intent);
```

in *SecondActivity*:

```
 Dice mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Dices");

 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
 textView.setText(mDice.getDiceNumber());
```

But it crashes. I know how to pass an object of it was just one object and not a whole array. But whenever I try to pass whole array it crashes. I have also tried with

```
Dice mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra()("Dices");
//and also with defining my mDice[] as Parcelable like this
Parcelable mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra()("Dices");
```

but with no luck. Please help me!

**EDIT:**

I tried to change my `Dice mDice[]` to `Parcelable mDice[]` and now I am able to open my second activity without crashing the app. However I cannot retrieve my values as my mDice[] does not have the methods  `mDice[0].getDiceNumber()` and `mDice[0].isDiceClicked()` for some reason.

in *SecondActivity*:

```
 Parcelable mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Dices");

 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
 textView.setText(mDice[0].getDiceNumber()); // here I get an error saying Cannot resolve method 'getDiceNumber' in 'Parcelable'
```

Comment: `But it crashes` what is the stack trace, please add your logs to your question

Comment: Also, your question doesn't have anything to do with android studio, other than the fact you're using it to develop your app, so there's no need to use the tag

Comment: You are suppose to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra`.

Comment: So I have tried like this: `Parcelable mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("Dices");` and it starts the other activity without crashing. The thing is now I cannot get the attributes in my Dice class to show up in my secondactivity. When I try `mDice[0].` there is not `getdicenumber()` or `isdiceclicked()`

Comment: @a_local_nobody

Comment: You are passing a single dice from first activity and expecting an array of dices on the second. it is bound to fail.

Comment: @SMR How am I passing a single dice? my mDice contains the whole array of Dice objects I created, or am I wrong?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Please check edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the line, where the issue is;

```
textView.setText(mDice.getDiceNumber())
```

It must be like below;

```
textView.setText(mDice[0].getDiceNumber())
```

Edits:

To answer your updated question,

You are trying to fetch the required fields from the **Parcelable[]** array. YOu have to actually cast it to Dice Object.

Example :

```
Parcelable[] dices = 
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArray("Dices");
Dices[] newDices = new Dice[dices.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < dices.length; i++) {
   newDices[i] = (Dice)dices[i];
   newDices[i].getDiceNumber() // This will give you the result
}
```

Comment: Please use the code format for your codes.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Hi, This does not work since I use `Parcelable mDice[] = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra()("Dices");` so when trying to write `mDice[0].getDiceNumber()`  and error says "Cannot resolve method 'getDiceNumber' in 'Parcelable'"

Comment: @Mohammed,
Please make your variables `private` .


   **private int mDiceNumber;**


   **private boolean mDiceClicked = false;**

Comment: @Sohail I did but it does not help. Please check I edited question.

Comment: @Mohammed, getParcelableArrayExtra method returns **Parcelable[]**. You have to cast it to **Dice** class.

Comment: @Sohail When trying to cast it to `Dice` with `Parcelable mDice[] = (Dice) getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("Dices");` it says `inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.os.Parcelable[]' to 'com.bignerdranch.android.thirtythrows.Dice'`

Comment: Don't cast it like that. You have to loop through mDice array. use for loop. Inside for loop,  

**Dice dice = (Dice)mDice[0]; **

Comment: @Mohammed, Please check my updated answer. Let me know, if it works for you

Comment: @Sohail Thanks!!!! It finally worked! I owe you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Gson().

In your FirstActivity:

```
 String strDice = new Gson().toJson(listOfStickerObject);

intent.putExtra("Dices", mDice);

>>Get the value From Second Activity:
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strDice = getIntent().getStringExtra("Dices");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Dice>>(){}.getType();
List<Dice> dice= gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```